# Show that $v(P+v^Tv)^{-1}v^T \in (0,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $P$ be positive definite $n \times n$ matrix and $v$ is an $n$-dimensional row matrix. Show that $$v(P+v^Tv)^{-1}v^T \in (0,1)$$

Since $P$ is positive definite, we know that $vPv^T\ge0$ and equivalently all the eigenvalues are positive. But I cannot apply these to the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are working with real matrices and vectors.

Notice that $P+v^Tv$ is still a positive definite matrix, and thus it is invertible.
Call $z$ the vector such that
$$
(P+v^Tv)z^T = v^T.
$$
If we multiply by $z$, we get
$$
zPz^T + (vz^T)^2 = vz^T \implies vz^T > (vz^T)^2 \implies 0<vz^T<1
$$
and
$$
vz^T = v(P+v^Tv)^{-1}v^T.
$$
This more or less mimics the proof of [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Comment: I didn't get "$zPz^T + (vz^T)^2 = vz^T$" this part well. Where does it come from? At the RHS shouldn't it be $zv^T$ instead?

Comment: Notice that $zv^T = vz^T$

Comment: You mean $zv^T$ is symmetric?

Comment: $zv^T$ is a scalar number

Comment: Oh right, now got it :)

Comment: But how do we prove that such $z$ exists at the beginning?

Comment: $z^T$ is defined exactly as $(P+v^Tv)^{-1}v^T$